# Flutter -Trying to transfer data to a bluetooth variable in another page-DeviceId

Tags: flutter, dart, pubspec

Please do not be afraid by seeing the code only. I pasted the whole for your reference. The issue, I am trying to save data in `save()` async function in the `ThermometerRegistration.dart`. I use DeviceId from `bleModels.dart`.

I want to use the value for this device saved from shared preference in ThermometerRegistration.dart to `blecontroller.dart`.

However, the error response is failed call back from the terminal. Also, my thermometer does not connect.

However, if I am using id: XX:XX:XX:XX:XX-Real mac, my thermometer gets connected-meaning that I probably am not being able to transfer data between pages.

Can anyone assist? Just focus on the part of the code I mentioned where the problem is happening. I just pasted the whole code for your understanding and reference.

**bleModels.dart**

```
class bleModels {

 String DeviceId;

 bleModels({

   this.DeviceId,
}

    );
}
```

**RegisterThermometer.dart**

```
import 'dart:developer';


import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';
import 'package:attendanceapp/models/bleModels.dart';
import 'package:attendanceapp/commons.dart';
import 'appData.dart';

SharedPreferences prefs;
final bleModels BleModels=bleModels();
class ThermoRegistration extends StatelessWidget {
  static Future init() async {
    prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();

  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: InitiateRegistration(),
    );
  }
}

class InitiateRegistration extends StatelessWidget {
  final TextEditingController _MacIDControllerText=TextEditingController();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(

      body: Center(
        child: Container(
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              Padding(
padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                child:  TextField(

                  obscureText: false,
                  controller: _MacIDControllerText,
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                    labelText:'Please key in the physical address of your device',
                    border: OutlineInputBorder(),

                  ),
                ),

              ),
              Text(
                "Digital Thermometer",
                style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 15,
                    color: Colors.blue,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
              ),
              SizedBox(
                height: 50,
              ),
              RaisedButton(child: Text("Register your device"), onPressed: save),
              RaisedButton(child: Text("Fetch Data"), onPressed: fetch),
              RaisedButton(child: Text("Delete Data"), onPressed: remove)
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

save() async {
  await ThermoRegistration.init();

  prefs.setString('string',BleModels.DeviceId);

}

 fetch() async {



 String Stringval = prefs.getString('string') ?? '';

 BleModels.DeviceId=Stringval;


  log(" $Stringval");


}

remove() async {
  prefs.remove('int');
}
```

**bleController.dart**

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:developer';
import 'package:attendanceapp/RegistertThermometer.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_reactive_ble/flutter_reactive_ble.dart';
import 'package:fluttertoast/fluttertoast.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';
import 'package:attendanceapp/commons.dart';
class BleController {
  final frb = FlutterReactiveBle();

  String deviceID=BleModels.DeviceId;
  StreamSubscription<ConnectionStateUpdate> connection;
  QualifiedCharacteristic rx;
  RxString status ='DEVICE NOT CONNECTED'.obs;
  RxString temperature = ' '.obs;

  void connect() async {

    connection = frb.connectToDevice(id: '$deviceID', connectionTimeout: const Duration(seconds: 5)).listen((state) {
      if (state.connectionState == DeviceConnectionState.connected) {

        status.value = 'CONNECTED!';

        // get rx
        rx = QualifiedCharacteristic(
            serviceId: Uuid.parse("0000fff0-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb"),
            characteristicId:
                Uuid.parse("0000fff1-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb"),
            deviceId: '$deviceID');


        // subscribe to rx
// ignore: unnecessary_statements
print(deviceID);
        frb.subscribeToCharacteristic(rx).listen((data)  {
          print("Hello");

          print(data);
          print(data.elementAt(5));
          print(data.elementAt(6));
          print((data.elementAt(4) * 256 + data.elementAt(5)) / 10);
          double final_temp =
              (data.elementAt(4) * 256 + data.elementAt(5)) / 10;
          String final_temp_value = final_temp.toString();
          temperature.value = final_temp_value;


        });
      }
      else{
        status.value='DEVICE NOT CONNECTED';
      }


  });
  }

  void disconnect() async {
    connection.cancel();
  }
}
```

OUTPUT:

```
E/DartMessenger(18243): Uncaught exception in binary message listener
E/DartMessenger(18243): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Reply already submitted
E/DartMessenger(18243):     at io.flutter.embedding.engine.dart.DartMessenger$Reply.reply(DartMessenger.java:431)
E/DartMessenger(18243):     at io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel$IncomingMethodCallHandler.onMessage(MethodChannel.java:282)
E/DartMessenger(18243):     at io.flutter.embedding.engine.dart.DartMessenger.invokeHandler(DartMessenger.java:296)
E/DartMessenger(18243):     at io.flutter.embedding.engine.dart.DartMessenger.lambda$dispatchMessageToQueue$0$DartMessenger(DartMessenger.java:320)
E/DartMessenger(18243):     at io.flutter.embedding.engine.dart.-$$Lambda$DartMessenger$TsixYUB5E6FpKhMtCSQVHKE89gQ.run(Unknown Source:12)
E/DartMessenger(18243):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:907)
E/DartMessenger(18243):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
E/DartMessenger(18243):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:216)
E/DartMessenger(18243):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7625)
E/DartMessenger(18243):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
E/DartMessenger(18243):     at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:524)
E/DartMessenger(18243):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:987)
E/MethodChannel#flutter_reactive_ble_method(18243): Failed to handle method call
E/MethodChannel#flutter_reactive_ble_method(18243): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: null is not a valid Bluetooth address
E/MethodChannel#flutter_reactive_ble_method(18243):     at android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice.<init>(BluetoothDevice.java:774)
E/MethodChannel#flutter_reactive_ble_method(18243):     at android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter.getRemoteDevice(BluetoothAdapter.java:671)
E/MethodChannel#flutter_reactive_ble_method(18243):     at com.polidea.rxandroidble2.internal.util.RxBleAdapterWrapper.getRemoteDevice(RxBleAdapterWrapper.java:36)
E/MethodChannel#flutter_reactive_ble_method(18243):     at com.polidea.rxandroidble2.internal.DeviceModule.provideBluetoothDevice(DeviceModule.java:39)
E/MethodChannel#flutter_reactive_ble_method(18243):     at com.polidea.rxandroidble2.internal.DeviceModule_ProvideBluetoothDeviceFactory.get(DeviceModule_ProvideBluetoothDeviceFactory.java:24)
E/MethodChannel#flutter_reactive_ble_method(18243):     at com.polidea.rxandroidble2.internal.DeviceModule_ProvideBluetoothDeviceFactory.get(DeviceModule_ProvideBluetoothDeviceFactory.java:10)
E/MethodChannel#flutter_reactive_ble_method(18243):     at com.polidea.rxandroidble2.internal.RxBleDeviceImpl_Factory.get(RxBleDeviceImpl_Factory.java:31)
```